# How to Setup Multi Website With Visible Language Codes in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, multistore, url, multi-website

I want to setup the below url structure in our website.

http://www.domain.com/en -> website: domain / storeview: domain_en

http://www.domain.com/de -> website: domain / storeview: domain_de

http://www.domain.com/es -> website: domain / storeview: domain_es

http://www.domain1.com/en -> website: domain1 / storeview: domain1_en

http://www.domain1.com/de -> website: domain1 / storeview: domain1_de

http://www.domain1.com/es -> website: domain1 / storeview: domain1_es

http://www.domain2.com/en -> website: domain2 / storeview: domain2_en

http://www.domain2.com/de -> website: domain2 / storeview: domain2_de

http://www.domain2.com/es -> website: domain2 / storeview: domain2_es

> **I don't want to create domain and sub domain. Magento not allow to create storeview with same name like "en". because "en" in all three
>   websites.**

how i can acheive this.

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Here are the following steps you need to take on.

> 1. Create 3 websites (domain, domain1 & domain2) from backend admin.
> 2. Create 3 Stores, 1 per website.(from backend admin.)
> 3. Create 9 Store Views, 3 per store. (from backend admin.)
> 4. Update .htaccess to redirect different links to you code.

Refer the following link for more details 
https://webkul.com/blog/multi-website-setup-in-magento-2/

Hope it finds you helpful.

Comment: Can you look at url. I don't want to create domain and sub domain. Magento not allow to create storeview with same name like en. because en in all three websites.

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow these steps

1. Create a website

   Go to admin panel->Stores->Settings->All Stores->Create Website
2. Create a Store

   Go to admin panel->Stores->Settings->All Stores->Create Website

   (you can create as many websites and stores as per your requirement)
3. To show the store code in URL

   Go to admin panel->Stores->Settings->Configuration->General->Web->Add Store Code to Urls and change the value to yes

Comment: Can you look at url. I don't want to create domain and sub domain. Magento not allow to create storeview with same name like en. because en in all three websites.